# 1.0.3 kibana-logging api link fails on flannel ip address timeout

Tags: kubernetes

I get the following error

```
Error: 'dial tcp 10.10.92.15:5601: i/o timeout'
Trying to reach: 'http://10.10.92.15:5601/'
```

10.10.92/24 is the flannel0 network on one of the kube slaves

Pods are up and running

```
elasticsearch-logging-v1-l1hu9   1/1       Running   0          1h
elasticsearch-logging-v1-rsgby   1/1       Running   0          1h
kibana-logging-v1-4wwfg          1/1       Running   0          1h
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to flannel not running on the kubernetes master, after I got flannel up, the url /api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kibana-logging worked.

THe HOWTO for kubernetes I used excluded setting up flannel on the master.